# MySQL STR_TO_DATE "Incorrect date value" in Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm getting this error when using Python's MySQL Connector library:

```
Incorrect date value: 'STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-19T16:57:56Z','%Y-%m-%d%@%H:%i:%s%@')' for column 'estimated_delivery'
```

Essentially I'm using this matching string: `%Y-%m-%d%@%H:%i:%s%@`

For this input: `2017-10-19T16:57:56Z`

I'm confused about where this error possibly could be =/

Comment: I do not think it is the pattern within `STR_TO_DATE()` that causes the error message. I think the entire `'STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-19T16:57:56Z','%Y-%m-%d%@%H:%i:%s%@')'` is regarded as a date value - which it is not.

Comment: @Shadow what do you mean STR_TO_DATE is not a date value? That feels contrary to the name of the function. If it's not a date, what is it?

Comment: You got me wrong: it is not the **output** of the function that I meant. The code seems to consider the whole `'STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-19T16:57:56Z','%Y-%m-%d%@%H:%i:%s%@')'` as data, not as a function name and parameter. It would be great to see how you try to execute the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see, I was inserting this STR_TO_DATE function into the SQL statement as a parameter to the execute function. This obviously made it inserted as a string instead of SQL syntax, silly mistake on my part.